# Android driver test run slow, how to make it faster

Tags: java, android, webdriver

I am using Android Driver to test a webview application. In our application we are using Android driver to test it in android simulator and device. We are using CSS locator to access element and its too slow. Does any one know how to make test run faster in emulator and device?

Thanks in advance,
RP